# Android - How to add views into layout programmlty

Tags: android

I would like to know if there is any way to create spinner view and attach it to the layout multiple time.

For example, I want to create an `For loop` that will create spinner view and attach it layout.

Something like that

**CODE**

```
 LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
 for(int i = 0;i <4;i++){
 Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
 layout.addView(spinner);
 setContentView(layout);
 }
```

Something like that.

Is it possible to create?

Comment: You don't need to call `setContentView` 4 times, you don't need it at all.

Comment: Yes, there is something like that and there are RecyclerViews. But if you want to do it the way you say it should be done after the setContentView() is done.

Comment: What do you mean after the setContentView() is done? I'm kinda lost and not sure what to do. Can you please direct me what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it helps :

[Image Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOwui.jpg)

Java :

```
LinearLayout root = findViewById(R.id.root);

        String[] spinnerArray = {"foo","baar"};

        for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
            Spinner spinner = new Spinner(MainActivity.this);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            param.setMargins(5,5,5,5);
            spinner.setLayoutParams(param);

            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
            spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

            root.addView(spinner);
        }
```

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```